# For arraylists in java, why is the return of the function set not void?

Tags: java, data-structures

In class, the set method for arraylist was as such:

```
public class ArrayList{
    private Shape[] arr;
    private int size;

    public Shape set(int i, Shape e){ 
        if (i>=0 && i<size){
            Shape tmp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = e;
            return tmp;
        }
        else{ 
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand why there is a return type at all. I tried googling and chatGPTing without success.

Comment: I can guess `arr` is a `Shape []`. But, where is there an `ArrayList` in your code?

Comment: But, anyway, putting that aside, whoever wrote the specs for the `Shape set (int i, Shape e)` method thought it might be useful in some cases to return the former value of `arr [i]`.  So, why not offer it? If it isn't needed, the programmer writing the code that calls `Shape set (int i, Shape e)` method is free to ignore the returned value.

Comment: It’s just returning the displaced item - might be useful in some cases and reduces the need for a caller to lookup the current item first - in cases where a List operation is not optimised for random access, it would provide a performance improvement (one action instead of two)

Comment: Also, this is a requirement enforced by the List interface which ArrayList implements

Comment: The code you posted is incorrect. It doesn't have a return value in the case that the `if` condition fails. Is that the real code?

Comment: Mr. Brown, have you read my answer?

Comment: The code is part of defining the ArrayList class. I'm missing some code preceding what I posted, which is defining the class ArrayList, and initializing the fields Shape[] arr and int size. I'll edit for clarity.

Comment: @user16320675 you are right, you must throw an except otherwise. Should be fixed now

Comment: By the way, having a non-void return type makes it more flexible. One could, for example, use an invocation of the method as an argument in another method. `foo.bar (3, shapeList.set (i, new Pentagon ()), 47.24);` for a dumb hypothetical example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple Answer: It's convenient.

There are many times when we use the `.set()` method on an `ArrayList` when we still want to store the old value. If this functionality did not exist it would mean writing an extra line (and programmers hate writing extra lines when it is just as readable not to). Consider the scenario of having a list of shapes, but we sometimes want to replace old shapes with new shapes, when we do this we want to print out the old shape, without the `return` on the `.set()` we would have to do it like this:

```java
List<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();

* populate the list *

int index = 3;
Shape oldShape = shapes.get(index);
Shape newShape = new Shape("Pentagon");

shapes.set(index, newShape);
System.out.println(oldShape);
```

With the `return` it allows us to concisely do this:

```java
List<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();

* populate the list *

Shape newShape = new Shape("Pentagon");
System.out.println(shapes.set(3, newShape));
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer makes it clear I had a conceptual error. I had thought that the function .set() "should" discard the oldShape after modifying the array with newShape, but in fact I should think of .set() as swapping the oldShape for the newShape.

Answer (score 0):

Thread safety.

Consider:

```
List<Integer> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
....
var old = list.set(4, 5);
```

This approach would always work, independently of activity in other execution threads.

Now consider:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
....
synchronized(list) {
    var old = list.get(4);
    list.set(4, 5);
}
```

This approach requires cooperative locking in other threads, which may not always be possible (for example, if list is used in a third-party library).

In general, a thread-safe interface strives to provide methods useful in a single "atomic" invocation, as multiple invocations may be hard to synchronize.